# How to log in Cakephp vendor Table class?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I try to debug a EmailQueueTable (extends Cake\ORM\Table) located in vendor folder, but I can't find how to get logs. 
I tried $this->out() (the method is called by SenderShell extends Cake\Console\Shell)
I tried $this->log
I tried Log::write
The only solution I found is to throw an Exception...

I would like to say that $this->log works well in other classes of the app.

If someone as an idea of the problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`$this->log` works in classes that have included the `LogTrait`. This includes Cake's core View, Controller and Component classes. I'm not sure why Table doesn't also include this, but you can get the same functionality with `\Cake\Log\Log::write(LogLevel::ERROR, $xxx);`